# ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper is locking WinService exe file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have following (simplified) code for installing WinService:

```
    public static bool InstallService(string fullFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { fullFileName });
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I noticed that when calling it in my installation wizard, EXE file of an WinService is locked until whole installation wizard is not finished. Is there any way how to avoid this lock? How to "free resources" just after InstallService is done? I found similar issue [here](https://codeplex.codeplex.com/discussions/19519). GC.Collect() did not help me.

I tried to call method in separate thread, but without success.

Comment: That's normal, assemblies loaded with Assembly.LoadFrom() stays loaded and keeps a lock on the file until the AppDomain is unloaded.  You'd have to run this code in a new AppDomain and unload it yourself to avoid this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some research I found solution which does not lock service's executable.

```
public static bool InstallService(string fullFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ai = new AssemblyInstaller(fullFileName, null))
            {
                ai.Install(null);
                ai.Commit(null);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```